# What is this annoying term in speed of relativistic center of mass?

Tags: special-relativity

Let's define relativistic center of mass in this way 
\begin{equation}
 \mathbf{r}_{cm} = \frac{\sum_i \gamma_i m_i \mathbf{r_i}}{\sum_i \gamma_i m_i}
\end{equation}
If system is isolated the total mass is constant and the speed at which center of mass goes is
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{v}_{cm} = \frac{\sum_i \dot{\gamma_i} m_i \mathbf{r_i} + \sum_i \gamma_i m_i \mathbf{u_i}}{\sum_i \gamma_i m_i}
\end{equation}
Using uppercase for total quantities I can rearrange in this way
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{P} = M \mathbf{v}_{cm} - \sum_i \dot{\gamma_i} m_i \mathbf{r_i} 
\end{equation}
This remember a classical theorem, but the sum $\sum_i \dot{\gamma_i} m_i \mathbf{r_i}$ is annoying. What does it mean? Is it constant? If energy and momentum are constant, center of mass doesn't move at constant speed?

Comment: You need to define your symbols with more care before you can work this problem.  What are the $\gamma_i$s? What speeds do they use? What is $M$? And so on.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_of_mass_(relativistic) about how the center of mass is not a well-defined concept in relativity.

Comment: Note that the system momentum (and thus a ``center of momentum'' frame) is well defined which (with a proper definition of system mass) makes a velocity for the system well defined.

Comment: @dmckee maybe I was not clear. M is total mass and $\gamma_i$ is Lorentz factor of i particle.

Comment: But how are you defining total mass (I know of at least three ways, two of which are defensible)? And for the Lorentz factors what are you taking the speed relative (this factors into the definition of the total mass that may (or may not) make sense in you expressions). You really do have to be *careful* in working problems like this or you risk tripping on your own toes.

Comment: The speed $u_i$ (from which I get $\gamma_i$) is the one of the particle measured by an inertial observer which has syncronized his own clocks. And total mass is the sum of total energy divided by $c^2$, or the sum of the $\gamma_i m_i$. Isn't the total energy the sum of the energy of the particles?

Comment: That is a defensible definition of the system mass if we can ignore potential terms between the components of the system (as would be the case for a typical "rigid enough" solid object that is not experiencing any strain or a system of non-interacting particles). But in those cases, what are the $\dot\gamma_i$s?

Comment: Your expression for $v_{cm}$ is wrong as you did not allow for differentiating the denominator.  The total mass (assuming you mean $\sum \gamma_i m_i$) cannot be assumed constant unless the $\gamma_i$ are.

Comment: The fact that we consider a rigid body does not change the meaning of the $\gamma_i$ and of their derivative, which is proportional to $\gamma_i^3$ dot the scalar product of $u_i \cdot a_i$, or to the scalar product of $F_i \cdot u_i$. This will help me? @StephenG why should the total mass constancy imply the constancy of the $\gamma_i$s? They can change leaving sum constant.

Comment: You cannot *presume* the total mass sum is constant, as you are doing (unless you can prove that independently).  Any interactions or collisions will invalidate this assumption.  Likewise any rotation may invalidate it, as rotation implies constantly changing velocities.  Your own formula includes $\dot{\gamma_i}$ which implies you consider they can change.  You can't have it both ways unless you can prove the total (relativistic) mass is constant.

Comment: For a stationary simply rotating rigid body all $\dot{\gamma_i}$ are zero, but this is not true in the general case. To simplify things, on the one hand I am driven to consider the rigid body and on the other to abandon it and include deformations or thermal considerations. All these comments are starting to give me a headache. What a complicated problem.